# Django Rest Framework: empty request.data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I have the following code for a view of DRF:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def update(self, request, pk = None):
        print pk
        print request.data
```

I call the URL via *python-requests* in the following way:

```
import requests
payload = {"foo":"bar"}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.put("https://.../myPk", data= payload, headers=headers)
```

but when the request is received from the server, request.data is empty. Here there is the output:

```
myPk
<QueryDict: {}>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try using requests.post

Comment: Mikeec3 the doc of rest framwork says:

_request.data returns the parsed content of the request body. This is similar to the standard request.POST and request.FILES attributes except that:

- It includes all parsed content, including file and non-file inputs.
**- It supports parsing the content of HTTP methods other than POST, meaning that you can access the content of PUT and PATCH requests.**
- It supports REST framework's flexible request parsing, rather than just supporting form data. For example you can handle incoming JSON data in the same way that you handle incoming form data._

Comment: I'm having the same issue but only if I use a custom parser, and even if the parser is 1-1 with the default one, same thing word for word copied and pasted into a new module, same problem occurs. It only happens when using json body, rather than the form data from the UI.  I can see the data coming in as request.body but not request.data. If I remove my custom parser, its back to normal both request.body and request.data are filled. My stream.read() looks exactly the same, its just that request.body is filled, while request.data is not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340257/parsing-multipart-form-data-in-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to send the `payload` as a serialized `json` object.

```
import json
import requests
payload = {"foo":"bar"}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.put("https://.../myPk/", data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Otherwise what happens is that DRF will actually complain about:

```
*** ParseError: JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded
```

You would see that error message by debugging the view (e.g. with [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) or [ipdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb)) or printing the variable like this:

```
def update(self, request, pk = None):
    print pk
    print str(request.data)
```

Comment: I tried to serialize the dictionary as a json but it still not working. When I read the print of the var values I get always `myPk` and `<QueryDict: {}>`.

Comment: What output do you get when you do `print request.stream.read()` instead of `print request.data` (it's important to remove `print request.data` for that test). This should show you the unaltered raw data from your request. Do you see anything there? [.stream in the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#stream)

Comment: I added the line `print request.stream.read()` immediately after `def update(self, request, pk = None):`. The output is: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: Ok I solved! The issues was: (i) JSON serialization and (ii) trailing slash in the request URL. `r = requests.put("https://.../myPk/", data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)`. sthzg, if you update the URL of yout above answer, adding a trailing slashi, I can flag it as accepted (Hoping it is a regular operation for stackexchange...)

Comment: Glad you solved it. I actually thought about the trailing slash and used it in the testing code, but forgot to test it for errors without it. Updated the path in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Check 2 issues here:-

1. Json format is proper or not.
2. Url is correct or not(I was missing trailing backslash in my url because of which I  was facing the issue)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on a new enough version of requests you need to do:

```
import requests

payload = {"foo":"bar"}
r = requests.put("https://.../myPk", json=payload, headers=headers)
```

Then it will properly format the payload for you and provide the appropriate headers. Otherwise, you're sending `application/x-www-urlformencoded` data which DRF will not parse correctly since you tell it that you're sending JSON.

Comment: Ok, but I specify the format in `headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}`