# Parsing multipart/form-data in django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm having some difficulties parsing multipart form data when using the django-rest-framework.  I've set up a minimal view to just echo back the request data:

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser


class FileUpload(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser, )

    def post(self, request, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({'raw': request.data, 'data': request._request.POST,
                         'files': str(request._request.FILES)})
```

I am expecting that `raw` (slightly badly named I admit) contains effectively the same data as `request._request.POST` and `request._request.FILES`.

If I `POST` to the view with `Content-Type= application/x-www-form-urlencoded` this works as expected:

```
$ http -v --form POST http://localhost:8000/upload/api/ course=3 name=name

POST /upload/api/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.2

course=3&name=name

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 16:52:37 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "data": {
        "course": "3",
        "name": "name"
    },
    "files": "<MultiValueDict: {}>",
    "raw": {
        "course": "3",
        "name": "name"
    }
}
```

However if I post with `Content-Type=multipart/form-data` I get the following:

```
$ http -v --form POST http://localhost:8000/upload/api/ file@~/Projects/lms/manage.py course=3 name=name
POST /upload/api/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 577
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=634ec7c7e89a487b89c1c07c0d24744c
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.2

--634ec7c7e89a487b89c1c07c0d24744c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="course"

3
--634ec7c7e89a487b89c1c07c0d24744c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

name
--634ec7c7e89a487b89c1c07c0d24744c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="manage.py"

#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.local")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

--634ec7c7e89a487b89c1c07c0d24744c--

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 16:55:44 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "data": {
        "course": "3",
        "name": "name"
    },
    "files": "<MultiValueDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: manage.py ()>]}>",
    "raw": {}
}
```

Am I missing something here?  I am using HTTPIE to generate the requests here but the same behaviour exists with curl so I'm pretty sure that is not the problem.  I am using djangorestframework==3.3.0 and Django==1.8.4

EDIT:

It seems that `PUT`ing to the url (with an otherwise identical request) achieves the desired result:

```
$ http -v --form PUT http://localhost:8000/upload/api/ file@~/Projects/lms/manage.py course=3 name=name
PUT /upload/api/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 577
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=98feb59a8abe4bfb95a7321f536ed800
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.2

--98feb59a8abe4bfb95a7321f536ed800
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="course"

3
--98feb59a8abe4bfb95a7321f536ed800
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

name
--98feb59a8abe4bfb95a7321f536ed800
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="manage.py"

#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.local")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

--98feb59a8abe4bfb95a7321f536ed800--

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Allow: POST, PUT, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 18:10:34 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "data": {},
    "files": "<MultiValueDict: {}>",
    "raw": "<QueryDict: {'name': ['name'], 'course': ['3'], 'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: manage.py ()>]}>"
 }
```

So I could just use `PUT`.  That is however not ideal as the client does not control what the file is named or where it is located on the server.  `POST` is more appropriate in that sense.  In any sense, I don't see why `PUT` works when `POST` doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried leaving the content type out of the post altogether? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574998/django-rest-framework-send-multipart-form-data-with-file-and-other-data-to-api): if no content type is passed to the post method it automatically sets multipart/form-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a [known issue](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/3951) for the version you're using. Upgrading django rest framework to the latest version will solve the problem. However, you can PUT the request as a workaround.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I figured out eventually too.  Thanks for referencing the issue on Github, it means this question finally has an authoritative answer!

Comment: @maxf130 I have the same issue, can you please help??https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67976100/expected-a-list-of-items-but-got-type-str-in-django-rest-framework You can check the updated code