# "Expected a list of items but got type \"str\"." in django rest framework

Tags: json, django, api, django-rest-framework, form-data

I have an addproduct api in which frontend is sending a formdata in a post axios call. Formdata is used because there is an image field that need to be sent.

But I got the following error.

**"Expected a list of items but got type "str"." in django rest framework.**

The data is sent in the following form as shown below.

{

```
        "merchant": 8,
        "category": "[3,4]",
        "brand":2,
        "name":"pvahnjjthhgjhtest",
        "best_seller":true,
        "top_rated":false,        
        "collection":2,
        "description":"abc",
        "featured": false,            
        "availability": "in_stock",
        "warranty": "no_warranty",
        "rating":5,
        "main_product_image":null,            
        "services": "cash_on_delivery",
        "variants": "[1,2]"
    }
```

Here the main issue is on category and on variants.The error is also shown in these two fields. Since frontend is sending formdata, these two fields are sent as string. Now how can I handle these two fields on backend?? What I need is get 1 and 2 as pk .

**How to get pks from the string. I tried json.load but it doenst work.**

My models:

```
class Variants(models.Model):
    
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=70, default='OAXWRTZ_12C',blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20,default=500)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=SIZE, default='not applicable',blank=True,null=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=70, default="not applicable",blank=True,null=True)
    variant_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/images", blank=True,null=True)
    thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='variant_image',
                               processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 50)],
                               format='JPEG',
                               options={'quality': 60})
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=10,blank=True,null=True)  # available quantity of given product
    variant_availability = models.CharField(max_length=70, choices=AVAILABILITY, default='available')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Variants"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_id
```

#Product Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
   
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Seller,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=False)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # is product featured?
    best_seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    top_rated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)  # tags mechanism
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150,unique=True)
    main_product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/images", null=True, blank=True)
    thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='main_product_image',
                               processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 50)],
                               format='JPEG',
                               options={'quality': 60})
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,blank=True)       
    description = RichTextField(blank=True)
    #picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/images", null=True, blank=True)
    picture = models.ManyToManyField(ImageBucket,null=True,blank=True,verbose_name="Add extra 3 images")
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, 1),
                                               (2, 2),
                                               (3, 3),
                                               (4, 4),
                                               (5, 5))
                                      )
    availability = models.CharField(max_length=70, choices=AVAILABILITY, default='in_stock')
    warranty = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=WARRANTY, default='no_warranty')
    services = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=SERVICES, default='cash_on_delivery')
    variants = models.ManyToManyField(Variants,related_name='products')
```

My view:

```
class ProductAddAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        serializer = AddProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data,{
                "message":"Product has been created"
            })
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

**Update on the code:**

**The data is now being sent in the following way:**

```
name: TestNamae
category[0]: 7
category[1]: 23
brand: 7
collection: 11
availability: in_stock
warranty: no_warranty
service: cash_on_delivery
rating: 3
best_seller: true
top_rated: true
featured: true
main_product_image: (binary)
merchant: 2
variants[0][product_id]: fgfdg
variants[0][price]: 127
variants[0][quantity]: 1
variants[0][color]: red
variants[0][size]: M
variants[0][variant_availability]: not_available
variants[0][variant_image]: (binary)
variants[1][product_id]: fgfdg
variants[1][price]: 127
variants[1][quantity]: 1
variants[1][color]: red
variants[1][size]: M
variants[1][variant_availability]: not_available
variants[1][variant_image]: (binary)
```

But when sent like this, it says the category is required but when it is sent in a list [1,2] it works. The data needs to be sent in this way, because there are image field inside the array so Multipart form is to be used.

How to solve this??

Comment: Replace `"variants": "[1,2]"` with `"variants": [1,2]`, the same for `"category": [3,4]`.

Comment: Do you specifically need to handle this in django? This is clearly a front-end POST issue, not a backend django validation issue.

Comment: Can you please show us the `AddProductSerializer` class?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem and Trent. Yes the frontend has to send form-data, because of the presence of image, that's why it cant be sent in a list form instead in a string. Please help!!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hello Willem, I have updated my code. Can you please check it?? Since fronted is sending MUltipart form data, should I use MultiPartParser as a parser class in my view??

Comment: @Trent can you have a look at my Updated code??

Comment: @Django-Rocks Stick to the practices!!! You're updated code have nested data which is no good. Try creating variants beforehand and only sending variant ids. They correct way to send a multipart array (category and variants) depends on your form submission. Please include front-end form submission code as well.

Comment: @AliAsgari Hello its because the merchant user have to create a product and variants at the same time at one button click. Thats why the data is being sent like that. Creating variant and then creating a product wont be ui friendly.

Comment: Then you have to deal with the consequences. You can have your custom serializer to parse such a data out of the request and you have to override the update/save/create methods to handle nested creation according to the DRF documentations.

Comment: @AliAsgari Yes, thats my issue. How can i parse such data in  my serializer..can you give any code snippet example?? so that I can continue...The deadline is near and I have to finish this

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61161227/uploading-multiple-images-and-nested-json-using-multipart-form-data-in-django-re